# Using Fax4J With Multiple Fax Modems?

Tags: java, fax

Can anyone give me a quick rundown on how to send faxes in Java using Fax4J? The tutorial provided by the javadocs is sketchy at best. In particular, it doesn't teach you how to specify which fax modem you are calling; it only says `FaxClient faxClient=FaxClientFactory.createFaxClient();` but how does it work?

I downloaded the full fax4j code, and I noticed some files called FaxModem.java in there. How are those used?

Answer (score 1):

For someone who actually authored fax4j, cant agree with the comment about the tutorial because i am not sure you read it.

The factory is explained returns a client which is backed by an engine called spi.
There are many different spi types.
Some would use windows native api, some would run a process, others would send emails and http requests to remote providers and it is all based on your fax4j configuration.

All cofiguration options possible are detailed in the tutorial so for example if you want to send an email to spcific mail server that converts it to fax ypu would set email address and other needed properties in your fax4j.properties file.

So based on the way you are sending requires different config and its all in the tutorial.
However you didnt write how you want to send and of course fax4j doesnt support everything.
I think the main bulk of users use the windows native api spi so they actually dont configure anything for fax4j and instead configure the fax settings in their windows machine and thats it